# create new column using a dictionary key

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Take this dataframe `df`:

`df = pd.DataFrame({'col_1':['some text green', 'some text blue', 'some text dog', 'some text']})`

```
             col_1
0  some text green
1   some text blue
2    some text dog
3        some text
```

And take this dictionary:

`my_dict = {'color':['green', 'blue'],'animal':['dog']}`

I need to create a new column `new_col` searching if the string contains in `col_1`. The strings are given in the dictionary values. If so, I need to get the dictionary key and place it in the new column. If not, just place NaN.

The result should be:

```
             col_1 new_col
0  some text green   color
1   some text blue   color
2    some text dog  animal
3        some text     NaN
```

Comment: does it have to be a dictionary, and can we use a list?

Comment: i would like the simplest solution. could be a list, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def f(s):
    for k in my_dict:
        for v in my_dict[k]:
            if v in s:
                return k

df["new_col"] = df["col_1"].apply(f)
```